# Static Initialization in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static-variables

I was trying to execute the following code:

```
public class StaticTest {

    private static List<String> dat1;
    {
        dat1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }

    private StaticTest(){
        System.out.println(dat1.contains("a")); //Marked Line 2: this one is not throwing
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dat1.contains("a")); //Marked Line 1: This line throws null pointer 
        new StaticTest(); 
    }
}
```

I tried to execute the above code, I got `Null pointer exception` at Marked Line 1. But when I commented Marked Line 1 I got the output.

Why am I getting the exception in first case and not in second ?

When I use `private static List<String> dat1= new ArrayList<>();`, no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple:

```
System.out.println(dat1.contains("a"));
```

runs a constructor (because it is inside the constructor!). 
And part of running the constructor is: to run all non-static initializer blocks of a class.

Whereas:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(dat1.contains("a")); //Marked Line 1: This line
```

does only run your **static** initializers - but **no** constructor code (it does - but *after* that line).

So your problem is that this initializer block:

```
{
    dat1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

isn't *static*!

In other words: your problem is caused by mixing static/non-static in very  unhealthy ways. If a field is **static**, make sure that a **static** init code will initialize it.

Btw: the reasonable solution is to simply do:

```
private final static List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

This makes sure that the list is initialized as soon as possible; and then compiler will even tell you when you forgot to initialize it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed the "static" keyword before the block. I tested and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
{
    dat1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

This constructor block. Which will be executed every constructor after super() , so it will not run on Mark1 yet.

If you have code like this, it will be executed when class is loaded.

```
static {
    dat1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

more detail here 
http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php

Comment: It's an *initializer* block.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @kajal please refer to the correct code below:-

```
 public class StaticTest {

    private static List<String> dat1;
    static
    {
        dat1 = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    }

    private StaticTest(){
        System.out.println(dat1.contains("a")); //Marked Line 2: this one is not throwing
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dat1.contains("a")); //Marked Line 1: This line throws null pointer 
        new StaticTest(); 
    }
}
```

Instance block is executes when you create a instance of that class.
Question why you are getting the `NullPointerException` :-
Please find the below flow of the `StaticTest` class execution :-

1. First all the import class will load like :-

   1. `Object` class 2.`java.lang` Package Class 3.`java.util.ArrayList` Class.
2. The compiler goes through the StaticTest Class and allocate the Memory for the all the Static Members in your case it is **`dat1`**.
3. Now the javac compiler searches for the Static block for the execution. in your case their is no Static block.
4. Now the compiler executes the `main` method and executes the `System.out.println(dat1.contains("a"));` is called as **`null.contains("a");`** which trhows the execption but as i said the Instance block is executes when you create a instance of that class. so **`dat1`** is initialized when you create object `new StaticTest();`

Comment: Thanks Husnain. I tested the code and it works fine.

Comment: Hi @kajal, can you please vote up and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
{
    dat1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Is a non-static initializer. This is called, when you are calling the constructor with: `new StaticTest()`. After that `dat1` will be initialized.

You can change your code to static initializing by preceding it with the `static` keyword:

```
static
{
    dat1 = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Then it will work for both cases.